# Не могу найти плавающий баг в логике решения задачи на алгоритмы С++

Tags: c++, алгоритм, классы

Задача в тестирующей системе валится на 20 тесте. Доступа к тестам нет. Результат моделирование на мелких тестах совпадает с тем что выдаёт вывод.

Я проходи контест от Яндекса. Там дается задание. Я беру выбираю компилятор и отправляю код. Там мне показывают, какой тест я прошел, а какой не прошел, но показывают только номер теста, в котором СТРОГО нет входных данных, то есть я знаю что ТОЛЬКО ЧТО мое решение не прошло на 20 тесте, и все. Там могут быть любые числа. И вряд ли баг в тестирующей системе, да такое может быть, но скорее всего проблема в моей логике. И я не могу найти проблему в логике.

Я пытаюсь решить это с помощью классов. Я везде использую `long long`. Я много раз проверял логику. Я тестировал этот код на разных небольших входных данных(3 2, 3 3, 3 4, 4 4). Все эти примеры соответствуют тому, что я рассчитал сам.

**ТЕКСТ ЗАДАЧИ**

> В системе умного дома под управлением голосового помощника Лариса n
> устройств, соединяющихся между собой по сети LoRaWAN. Устройство номер
> 1 подключено к интернету и на него было скачано обновление, которое
> необходимо передать на все устройства. Сеть LoRaWAN очень медленная,
> поэтому для распространения протокола был придуман peer-to-peer (P2P)
> протокол. Файл обновления разбивается на k одинаковых по размеру
> частей, занумерованных от 1 до k.
>
> Передача части обновления происходит во время таймслотов. Каждый
> таймслот занимает одну минуту. За один таймслот каждое устройство
> может получить и передать ровно одну часть обновления. То есть
> устройство во время таймслота может получать новую часть обновления и
> передавать уже имеющуюуся у него к началу таймслота часть обновления,
> или совершать только одно из этих действий, или вообще не осуществлять
> прием или передачу. После приема части обновления устройство может
> передавать эту часть обновления другим устройствам в следующих
> таймслотах.
>
> Перед каждым таймслотом для каждой части обновления определяется, на
> скольких устройствах сети скачана эта часть. Каждое устройство
> выбирает отсутствующую на нем часть обновления, которая встречается в
> сети реже всего. Если таких частей несколько, то выбирается
> отсутствующая на устройстве часть обновления с наименьшим номером.
>
> После этого устройство делает запрос выбранной части обновления у
> одного из устройств, на котором такая часть обновления уже скачана.
> Если таких устройств несколько — выбирается устройство, на котором
> скачано наименьшее количество частей обновления. Если и таких
> устройств оказалось несколько — выбирается устройство с минимальным
> номером.
>
> После того, как все запросы отправлены, каждое устройство выбирает,
> чей запрос удовлетворить. Устройство A удовлетворяет тот запрос,
> который поступил от наиболее ценного для A устройства. Ценность
> устройства B для устройства A определяется как количество частей
> обновления, ранее полученных устройством A от устройства B. Если на
> устройство A пришло несколько запросов от одинаково ценных устройств,
> то удовлетворяется запрос того устройства, на котором меньше всего
> скачанных частей обновления. Если и таких запросов несколько, то среди
> них выбирается устройство с наименьшим номером.
>
> Далее начинается новый таймслот. Устройства, чьи запросы
> удовлетворены, скачивают запрошенную часть обновления, а остальные не
> скачивают ничего.
>
> Для каждого устройства определите, сколько таймслотов понадобится для
> скачивания всех частей обновления.
>
> Формат ввода:
>
> Вводится два числа n и k (2 ≤ n ≤ 100, 1 ≤ k ≤ 200).
>
> Формат вывода:
>
> Выведите n-1 число — количество таймслотов, необходимых для скачивания
> обновления на устройства с номерами от 2 до n.
>
> Пример:
> Ввод: 3 2
> Вывод: 3 3
>
> Ограничение времени:  15 секунд
>
> Ограничение памяти:   256Mb
>
> Ввод: стандартный ввод или input.txt
>
> Вывод:    стандартный вывод или output.txt

**Мое решение**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <climits>

using namespace std;

class Device {
public:
    Device(vector<Device*>& vd, long long k, vector<long long>& cu, long long n) {
        devices = &vd;
        commonUpdates = &cu;
        updates = vector<bool>(k, false);
        valueble = vector<long long>(n, 0);
        requests = vector<Device*>();
        countPartOfUpdates = 0;
        nowNeedpartOfUpdate = -1;
        iters = 0;
        indexInDevices = devices->size();
        devices->push_back(this);
    }

    void choose_part_of_update() {
        nowNeedpartOfUpdate = -1;
        long long minCountUpdates = LLONG_MAX;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < updates.size(); ++i) {
            if (updates[i] == false && (*commonUpdates)[i] < minCountUpdates) {
                minCountUpdates = (*commonUpdates)[i];
                nowNeedpartOfUpdate = i;
            }
        }
        if (nowNeedpartOfUpdate != -1) {
            ++iters;
        }
    }

    void choose_device_who_have_part_of_update() {
        if (nowNeedpartOfUpdate == -1) {
            return;
        }
        long long minDownloadUpdates = LLONG_MAX;
        long long iDevice = 0;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < devices->size(); ++i) {
            Device* dev = (*devices)[i];
            if (dev->updates[nowNeedpartOfUpdate] == true) {
                if (dev->countPartOfUpdates < minDownloadUpdates) {
                    iDevice = i;
                    minDownloadUpdates = dev->countPartOfUpdates;
                }
            }
        }
        (*devices)[iDevice]->requests.push_back(this);
    }

    void choose_request() {
        long long minCountPartOfUpdates = LLONG_MAX;
        long long iOkDevice = -1;
        long long maxValueble = -1;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < this->requests.size(); ++i) {
            Device* dev = requests[i];
            if (valueble[dev->indexInDevices] > maxValueble) {
                iOkDevice = dev->indexInDevices;
                minCountPartOfUpdates = dev->countPartOfUpdates;
                maxValueble = valueble[dev->indexInDevices];
            }
            else if (valueble[dev->indexInDevices] == maxValueble) {
                if (minCountPartOfUpdates > dev->countPartOfUpdates) {
                    iOkDevice = dev->indexInDevices;
                    minCountPartOfUpdates = dev->countPartOfUpdates;
                }
            }
        }
        this->requests.clear();
        if (iOkDevice != -1) {
            Device* dev = (*devices)[iOkDevice];
            ++(dev->countPartOfUpdates);
            dev->updates[dev->nowNeedpartOfUpdate] = true;
            ++((*commonUpdates)[dev->nowNeedpartOfUpdate]);
            ++(dev->valueble[this->indexInDevices]);
        }
    }

    vector<Device*>* devices;
    vector<long long>* commonUpdates;
    vector<bool> updates;
    vector<long long> valueble;
    vector<Device*> requests;
    long long countPartOfUpdates;
    long long nowNeedpartOfUpdate;
    long long iters;
    long long indexInDevices;
};

vector<long long> decide(long long n, long long k) {
    vector<Device*> devices;
    vector<long long> commonUpds(k, 1);

    for (long long i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        Device* dev = new Device(devices, k, commonUpds, n);
    }
    devices[0]->countPartOfUpdates = k;
    devices[0]->updates = vector<bool>(k, true);

    while (true) {
        long long thisIsEnd = 0;
        for (Device* dev : devices) {
            if (dev->countPartOfUpdates == k) {
                thisIsEnd += 1;
                continue;
            }
            dev->choose_part_of_update();
        }
        if (thisIsEnd == n) {
            break;
        }
        for (Device* dev : devices) {
            if (dev->countPartOfUpdates == k)
                continue;
            dev->choose_device_who_have_part_of_update();
        }
        for (Device* dev : devices) {
            if (dev->requests.size() == 0)
                continue;
            dev->choose_request();
        }
    }
    vector<long long> ans;
    for (Device* dev : devices) {
        ans.push_back(dev->iters);
    }
    return ans;
}

int main() {
    ifstream iFile("input.txt");
    long long n, k;
    iFile >> n >> k;

    vector<long long> v = decide(n, k);
    ofstream outputFile("output.txt");
    for (size_t i = 1; i < v.size(); ++i) {
        outputFile << v[i] << " ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («**почему этот код не работает?**») должны включать желаемое поведение, *конкретную проблему или ошибку* и *минимальный код* для её воспроизведения **прямо в вопросе**. Вопросы без **явного описания проблемы** бесполезны для остальных посетителей. См. [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @MarianD Проблема как раз в том что у меня нет теста, на котором валится решение, но проблема в логике есть, и я её не могу увидеть. Также я не могу синтезировать тест, так как на минимальных тестах (3 2, 3 3, 3 4, 4 3) я логически сам прорешал и ответ совпадал с выводом. А все что выше банально сожно самому логически пропрешать, так как количество ходов будет ужасно большим

Comment: Я не понимаю — откуда вы взяли, что в вашей программе есть логическая ошибка, когда вы не можете ни ее увидеть, ни ваши тесты никакой ошибки не обнаружили?

Comment: @MarianD я проходи контест от яндекса. Там дается задание. я беру выбираю компилятор и отправляю код. Там мне показывают какой тест я прошел, а какой не прошел, но показывают только номер теста, в котором СТРОГО нет входных данных, то есть я знаю что ТОЛЬКО ЧТО мое решение не прошло  на 20 тесте, и все. Там могут быть любые числа. И вряд ли баг в тестирующей системе, да такое может быть, но скорее всего проблема в моей логике. И я не могу найти проблему в логике.

Comment: Добавите это ваше объяснение прямо в ваш вопрос (клик на **Править** под ним). Я затем буду голосовать за его повторное открытие.

Comment: @MarianD добавил, даже еще немного побольше

Comment: Отлично. Я уже голосовал за переоткрытие вашего вопроса, нужны еще 4 голоса.

Comment: В общем, спустя 4 дня мучения я понял в чем проблема. Все дело в том что я в фунции `choose_request()` я менял "ценность" обьекта у которого был запрошен запрос, для обьекта который этот запрос делал, из за чего могла образоваться ситуация, когда обьект 3 делал себя более ценным для обьекта 5, который из за этого теперь будет выбирать обьект 3, а не обьект скажем 2(если бы 2 и 3 имели бы одинаковую ценность))

Как решил. Вынес в отдельную функцию удовлетворения запроса обьекта, и вынес вызов у всех обьектов данную функцию ПОСЛЕ подсчета выбора чей запрос удовлетворить.

Comment: Отлично! Теперь вы можете ваше решение предоставить в виде ответа (да, возможно ответить и на свой собственный вопрос) и получить за него баллы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема заключалась в функции `choose_request()` менялась "ценность" объекта, у которого был запрошен запрос, для объекта который этот запрос делал, из-за чего могла образоваться ситуация, когда объект 3 делал себя более ценным для объекта 5, который из-за этого теперь будет выбирать объект 3, а не объект скажем 2 (если бы 2 и 3 имели бы одинаковую ценность).

Вынес в отдельную функцию удовлетворения запроса объекта, и вынес вызов у всех объектов данную функцию ПОСЛЕ подсчета выбора чей запрос удовлетворить.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <limits>

using namespace std;

class Device {
public:
    Device(long long k, long long n) {
        updates = vector<bool>(k, false);
        valueble = vector<long long>(n, 0);
        requests = vector<Device*>();
        countPartOfUpdates = 0;
        nowNeedpartOfUpdate = -1;
        iters = 0;
        indexInDevices = devices.size();
        myRequestOK = false;
        idDeviceRequest = -1;
        devices.push_back(this);
    }

    void choose_part_of_update() {
        nowNeedpartOfUpdate = -1;
        long long minCountUpdates = std::numeric_limits<long long>::max();
        for (size_t i = 0; i < updates.size(); ++i) {
            if (updates[i] == false && commonUpdates[i] < minCountUpdates) {
                minCountUpdates = commonUpdates[i];
                nowNeedpartOfUpdate = i;
            }
        }
        if (nowNeedpartOfUpdate != -1) {
            ++iters;
        }
    }

    void choose_device_who_have_part_of_update() {
        if (nowNeedpartOfUpdate == -1) {
            return;
        }
        long long minDownloadUpdates = std::numeric_limits<long long>::max();
        Device* deviceRequest = nullptr;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < devices.size(); ++i) {
            Device* dev = devices[i];
            if (dev->updates[nowNeedpartOfUpdate] == true) {
                if (dev->countPartOfUpdates < minDownloadUpdates) {
                    deviceRequest = dev;
                    minDownloadUpdates = dev->countPartOfUpdates;
                }
            }
        }
        if (deviceRequest != nullptr) {
            deviceRequest->requests.push_back(this);
        }
    }

    void choose_request() {
        long long minCountPartOfUpdates = std::numeric_limits<long long>::max();
        long long iOkDevice = -1;
        long long maxValueble = -1;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < this->requests.size(); ++i) {
            Device* dev = requests[i];
            if (valueble[dev->indexInDevices] > maxValueble) {
                iOkDevice = dev->indexInDevices;
                minCountPartOfUpdates = dev->countPartOfUpdates;
                maxValueble = valueble[dev->indexInDevices];
            }
            else if (valueble[dev->indexInDevices] == maxValueble) {
                if (minCountPartOfUpdates > dev->countPartOfUpdates) {
                    iOkDevice = dev->indexInDevices;
                    minCountPartOfUpdates = dev->countPartOfUpdates;
                }
            }
        }
        this->requests.clear();
        if (iOkDevice != -1) {
            Device* dev = devices[iOkDevice];
            dev->myRequestOK = true;
            dev->idDeviceRequest = this->indexInDevices;
        }
    }

    void request_OK() {
        if (!myRequestOK)
            return;
        ++countPartOfUpdates;
        updates[nowNeedpartOfUpdate] = true;
        ++commonUpdates[nowNeedpartOfUpdate];
        ++valueble[idDeviceRequest];
        myRequestOK = false;
    }

    static vector<Device*> devices;
    static vector<long long> commonUpdates;
    vector<bool> updates;
    vector<long long> valueble;
    vector<Device*> requests;
    bool myRequestOK;
    int idDeviceRequest;
    long long countPartOfUpdates;
    long long nowNeedpartOfUpdate;
    long long iters;
    long long indexInDevices;
};

vector<Device*> Device::devices;
vector<long long> Device::commonUpdates;


vector<long long> decide(long long n, long long k) {
    Device::devices = vector<Device*>();
    Device::commonUpdates = vector<long long>(k, 1);
    for (long long i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        Device* dev = new Device(k, n);
    }
    Device::devices[0]->countPartOfUpdates = k;
    Device::devices[0]->updates = vector<bool>(k, true);
    while (true) {
        long long thisIsEnd = 0;
        for (Device* dev : Device::devices) {
            if (dev->countPartOfUpdates == k) {
                thisIsEnd += 1;
                continue;
            }
            dev->choose_part_of_update();
        }
        if (thisIsEnd == n) {
            break;
        }

        for (Device* dev : Device::devices) {
            if (dev->countPartOfUpdates == k)
                continue;
            dev->choose_device_who_have_part_of_update();
        }
        for (Device* dev : Device::devices) {
            if (dev->requests.size() == 0)
                continue;
            dev->choose_request();
        }
        for (Device* dev : Device::devices) {
            if (dev->myRequestOK == false) {
                continue;
            }
            dev->request_OK();
        }
    }

    vector<long long> ans;
    for (Device* dev : Device::devices) {
        ans.push_back(dev->iters);
    }
    for (Device* dev : Device::devices) {
        delete dev;
    }
    return ans;
}


int main() {
    ifstream iFile("input.txt");
    long long n, k;
    iFile >> n >> k;

    vector<long long> v = decide(n, k);
    ofstream outputFile("output.txt");
    for (size_t i = 1; i < v.size(); ++i) {
        outputFile << v[i] << " ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```